# Automapper Not mapped list dto to list

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, automapper

An interesting problem of this nature. I'm trying to map List to List. That is, to compare two homogeneous objects.
However, the mapper throws me an Exception

Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

I would be grateful for any help! I can't solve the problem all day.

```
   CreateMap<List<GrammarQuestionDTO>, TestDTO>()
        .ForMember(t => t.GrammarQuestion, map => map.MapFrom(source => source))
        .ForAllOtherMembers(x => x.Ignore());


public class GrammarQuestionDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public LevelType LevelType { get; set; }

    public QuestionType QuestionType { get; set; } = QuestionType.Grammar;

    public string Question { get; set; }

    public List<AnswerDTO> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class TestDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<GrammarQuestionDTO> GrammarQuestion { get; set; }

    public List<AuditionQuestionDTO> AuditionQuestion { get; set; }

    public string EssayTopic { get; set; }

    public string SpeakingTopic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your classes? GrammarQuestionDTO and TestDTO

Comment: sure. i add more info

Comment: Which list to which list are you trying to map? And why are you using `CreateMap<List<GrammarQuestionsDTO>, TestDTO>`? What are you trying to achieve?